# Tree shaking for Angular 2.x+ modules?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, tree-shaking

I don't know what I'm asking would still be called tree-shaking, but suppose I have two modules:

```js
CoreModule: {
  declarations: [Component_One, Component_Two, Component_Three],
  exports: [Component_One, Component_Two, Component_Three]
}

AppModule: {
  imports: [CoreModule]
}
```

In my app I am only ever using `Component_One`. The whole reason I import CoreModule is so I can use `Component_One`.

All three components exposed in CoreModule are totally independent of each other.

If I build the app with three shaking enabled, `Component_Two` and `Component_Three` will still be included in the final bundle, correct? Because they are imported by the `CoreModule`, even though they are totally irrelevant to my final app and not used anywhere.

So is there currently a way to tree shake them out of the final bundle?